# How to format datetime for a MySQL WHERE condition

Tags: python, mysql, variables

I am getting an error for my query. The error is

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '18:07:41' at line 1
```

First of all I don't understand what line 1 refers to since my query isn't at line 1 in my Python script.

My code looks like this

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='HOST.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',
    user='USER',
    passwd='PASSWORD',
    db='DBNAME')

    c = conn.cursor()

    value = datetime.now() - timedelta(5)

    value = value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    c.execute("SELECT temp, humidity, rain, datetime FROM data WHERE datetime >= (%s);" % (value))

    rows = c.fetchall()
```

And datetime is entered into the database in another script as

```
str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Is this even the best way to do this? I just want a timestamp for when a value was entered into the datebase.

I have tested using a different parameter in the query such as a value for temp

```
value = 10

        c.execute("SELECT temp, humidity, rain, datetime FROM data WHERE temp >= (%s);" % (value))
```

So I think it must be something with the way I am formatting the datetime however I'm not sure how to verify this.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Don't use string formatting on SQL strings, they lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Why are you putting parentheses around the date?

Comment: sorry, that's a mistake from trying something earlier. I don't actually have the parentheses

Comment: 3 answers, 3 needless string concatenations. The practice is just too widespread to stop now; even if this particular example is innocuous enough, why are people still perpetuating the idea that the way forward is string formatting? :(

Comment: So what should I do instead?

Comment: On my phone so will do my best; `c.execute("SELECT temp, humidity, rain, datetime FROM data WHERE datetime >= %s;", (value,))`. The `%s` of mysql is not the same as string formatting, note I swapped the second `%` for a comma (I'm instead passing two arguments to `execute`, not a single string that has been formatted). This escapes `value` and helps protect against SQL injection. Even if that's not an issue here, it's a consistent syntax that works even when there is no risk

Comment: Thank you very much. If you post this as an answer I will make sure to mark it as such

Answer (score -2):

Try it like this

```
"select * FROM table WHERE datetime => '{}' ". format(value)
```